# Linux Mint boot problem psmouse serio1: Failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dual-boot

I installed Linux Mint on my laptop successfully. Then I click "Restart Now". After that this black screen appeared.

[image]

I have no mouse attached to my laptop. My touchpad stopped working. I pressed F12 expecting boot menu, it didn't work. Neither did F11 or 'Esc'. I tried to kill boot using Alt+SysRq+K, but none of these are working. Nothing is happening on screen. Whenever I pressed F11 or F12 the following is coming onto the screen and nothing else is happening. This is my screen right now.

[image]

I don't know what else to do. I'm afraid of what would happen if I turn off the power.

Any help?